# How do I load a picture (image) into smalltalk

Tags: graphics, smalltalk, image, visualworks

How do you load a picture into smalltalk?  I have found several examples of how to display an image once it is a class resource, but can't find a way to import the picture into my smalltalk environment. (I use the word picture to avoid confusion with the smalltalk image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To load an image as a class resource, the following code should be executed in the workspace.

```
ImageReader imageFromFile: 'picture.bmp' 
    toClass: Namespace.MyClass selector: #AccessMethod
```

where 
'picture.bmp' is the image file you want to load,
NameSpace.MyClass is the class you want the file to be a resource to,
AccessMethod is the name of the method called to return the picture.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility for Squeak would be:

```
HandMorph attach: (SketchMorph fromStream:
  'https://squeak.org/img/features/morphic.png'
    asUrl retrieveContents contentStream).
```

(This used to work for Pharo, too, but seems to have been removed.)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but SketchMorph doesn't appear in my Pharo 7 image?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Thanks. I haven't used it for quite a while, but Pharo often drops old features for a leaner experience, so maybe they got rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Pharo Mooc](http://rmod-pharo-mooc.lille.inria.fr/OOPMooc/01-Welcome/W1S05-PharoSyntaxInANutshell.pdf):

```
(ZnEasy getPng: 'http://pharo.org/web/files/pharo.png')
asMorph openInWindow
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Pharo 7.0:

```
ImageReadWriter formFromStream: './assets/player.png' asFileReference binaryReadStream
```

Afterwards it can be transformed with `asMorph`.